# Are computed properties evaluated every time they are accessed?

Tags: swift, properties, computed-properties

I have two questions about computed properties in Swift.

Are computed properties evaluated every time they are accessed? Or they are stored somewhere for future access?

What kind of property is this, since I couldn't google it out:

```
let navigationController: UINavigationController = {
   var navigator = UINavigationController()
   navigator.navigationBar.translucent = false
   return navigator
}()
```

Is this also evaluated every time it is accessed?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### That is NOT a computed property.

```
let navigationController: UINavigationController = {
   var navigator = UINavigationController()
   navigator.navigationBar.translucent = false
   return navigator
}()
```

It is just a **stored property** populated with the result of the value returned by this block of code.

```
var navigator = UINavigationController()
navigator.navigationBar.translucent = false
return navigator
```

The block is executed when the instance of the class is instantiated. Only once.

So writing this

```
struct Person {
    let name: String = {
        let name = "Bob"
        return name
    }() // <- look at these
}
```

is **equivalent** to this

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    init() {
        self.name = "Bob"
    }
}
```

IMHO the first approach is better because:

- it does allow you to declared and populate a property in the **same "space"**
- it's more **clear**
- does prevent **duplication** of code if you have multiple initializers

### Note #1: Storing a closure inside a property

As *dfri* noted in the comment below, the block of code does end with `()`. It means that the code is **evaluated** and the result assigned to the property.

On the other hand, if we remove the `()` at the end of the block, we get something different, infact the block is **not** evaluated.
In this case Swift tries to assign a `stored closure` to the property. This will produce a compile error since the property has this type `UINavigationController`.

With the correct syntax we can put a closure inside a property.

```
struct Person {
    let sayHello: ()->() = { print("Hello") }
}
```

Now we have a `sayHello` property which contains a closure. The closure receives 0 parameters and does return `Void`.

```
let bob = Person()
bob.sayHello // this does NOT execute the code inside closure
bob.sayHello() // this does execute the code in the closure and does print the message
```

### Note #2: let's talk about Computed Properties

So we made clear that code in this question is **not** a `Computed Property`.
However, as *EmilioPelaez* noted in another comment below, we should also state that a `Computed Property` is evaluated **each time** it is accessed.

In the example below I created a Computed Property `age`. As you can see each time I invoke it, the code in the block gets executed as well.

*Example of a Computed Property (`age`)*

[image]

Comment: So this executes only ones, no matter how many times you call it? also what about computed ones, is their "implementation" evaluated every time?

Comment: Yep, the code is executed only once. You can add a `print("Test")` inside that block of code and verify it.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that `()` after final brace is key here (initialising `navigationController` property by running the anonymous closure block once). E.g. removing this final `()` and _"slightly"_ modifying the top line to `let navigationController: () -> (UINavigationController) = { ...` would yield a stored closure that returns `UINavigationController` instances with `.translucent = false`. This closure could in turn be used in place of the anonymous block above, i.e., with the closure name instead of the `{ ... }` block: `let myNavigationController = navigationController()`.

Comment: @dfri: I totally I agree. I will add this consideration to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: You should also add the answer to the first question, computer properties are computer every time they are accessed.

Comment: @appzYourLife A final note: I removed the `()` but also had to replace the `UINavigationController` type with the closure type `... : () -> (UINavigationController) = ...` instead of the prior `... :   UINavigationController = ...`. If we only remove `()` here, we'll get a compile time error. However we could leave explicit types out of it and let Swift infer these instead, so e.g. for `let foo = { () -> Int in 1 }()` the final `()` is the only difference between assigning `1` to `foo` (including final `()`, => `foo` is `Int`) or assigning the `() -> Int` closure to `foo` (leaving out `()`).

Comment: @dfri: Right! I updated my answer, let me know if you think everything is correct now. Thank you.

Comment: @appzYourLife Looks great!